# Why did USB/Serial communication between Raspberry Pi (Python) and several ESP32s fail?

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, esp32

My project is to establish a USB/Serial communication between a Raspberry Pi 4 model B, using Python (v. 3.9) and pySerial (v. 3.4), and several ESP32s (Arduino IDE). In each case, the Raspberry Pi initiates the communication.

Communications are relayed by hubs powered by 24 V. There are 4 hubs in the target configuration with up to 16 ESP32s.

What is happening is the following:

- If 7 ESP32s (or less) are connected, all works fine.
- If more (I need up to 16 ESP32s to be connected), the connection fails with some of the ESP32s (erratically: sometimes it works, sometimes not, and not always the same devices).

In all cases, Raspbian sees the connections in "/dev/ttyUSB*" very well, but pySerial fails (sometimes) when opening communication (112500, no handshake, so no RTS/CTS, as the ESP32 natively are).

Once the connection has failed "/dev/ttyUSB" files are no more readable, Arduino IDE is no more able to communicate with the ESP32, and I need to reset the hubs in order to establish communication again.

Do you have an explanation? Is there a limitation on the USB ports managed by the Raspberry Pi?

Here is a schematic for 9 ESP32s (I've tested several configurations, cascading or not the connections, but that changes nothing):

[image]

Comment: You are either running out of power to allow all devices to be connected, or out of some other resource like endpoints that the hubs or RPi can handle. How many endpoints each ESP32 take, 3? You never mention which Raspberry Pi you are using, as they have different USB controllers so they have different limits.

Comment: This is Rasp 4 model B. Each hub is powered by a 24 volts supply (I'll add a schematic for 9 ESP32s, editing the question. I don't know what you mean by "endpoint", could you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely hitting the limit of the number of USB endpoints you can have.

RPi 4 is limited to 30 endpoints (not counting the 2 that are already reserved).

Each USB device you can plug in can use a number of "logical pipes" for communication and where the "pipe" ends is called an "endpoint".

Typically each device requires a configuration endpoint and one or more endpoints for transferring data. As the ESP32 devices are USB serial ports, they require at least 3 endpoints per device, 1 for configuration, 1 for transmitted data, and 1 for received data.

Each USB hub also requires an endpoint to work, and each port on a hub also needs an endpoint.

So if you have 7 ESPs, that takes already 28 endpoints if the endpoints for hub input port is not calculated.

There are just no endpoints left to communicate with larger number of ESPs unless you have more USB controllers than one.

Comment: what you say makes sense, but could you clarify what "endpoint" means (why each ESP32 needs 3 endpoints?)? do you mean a endpoint is like a function as described here https://acroname.com/blog/how-many-usb-devices-can-i-connect ?

Comment: I did describe why ESP32 needs 3 endpoints (config, transmit, receive) and I did describe that an endpoint is a point where a virtual data pipe sent over USB ends.

Comment: Justme,thanks for your answer. OK, 30 endpoints max per Rasp. But, about the 3 endpoints required for each ESP32, why? Why one device corresponds to 3 endpoints? could you explain, please? Is "endpoint" comparable/the same as "function" in the link I've mentioned above?

Comment: And...In complement, do you have an idea to bypass that limitation (except multiplying the Rasp)? (UpVoted anyway)

Comment: And... (sorry for these several questions), where is documented the Rasp limit to 30 endpoints?

Comment: @lemon Justme said configuration, send, receive - that's 3. I assume the reason there's a hard limit is because there is a USB controller chip that has to know about all the endpoints and it has a certain number of slots to remember them by, and the Pi has a cheap controller with only 30 slots.

Comment: @lemon You need one endpoint to even determine what USB device you have, another endpoint to transmit data to it, and third to receive data as endpoints are unidirectional. And the limit was found by googling "raspberry pi endpoint limit" as many other people have also found it the hard way. Unless RasPi has multiple USB controllers, there is no way around the USB controller limit. On a PC you can simply add PCIe USB controller cards.

Comment: @lemon maybe you could make your own serial bus where all of them connect to one bus.